# What "resource: |" does mean in routes.yaml?

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to figure out with Sylius routing, based on Symfony framework. I found that code

```yaml
sylius_admin_channel:
    resource: |
        alias: sylius.channel
        section: admin
        templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
        except: ['show']
        redirect: update
        grid: sylius_admin_channel
        permission: true
        vars:
            all:
                subheader: sylius.ui.configure_channels_available_in_your_store
                templates:
                    form: "@SyliusAdmin/Channel/_form.html.twig"
            index:
                icon: share alternate
    type: sylius.resource
```

But I could not find any information what is it | for resource. Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the YAML syntax for a [multi-line string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines) (that preserves newlines).

So `sylius_admin_channel` is a mapping that has two keys (`resource` and `type`) whose values are both string types.

It can be confusing to see in this instance because the string *happens* to also be valid YAML. I edited your question to include syntax highlighting for YAML which makes this a little more obvious, visually.

If I didn't know any better, I would have guessed that the `|` is there in error and `resource` should actually have a mapping type for its value. If you remove the `|`, then same symbols that were within that string still produce valid YAML for the whole file, but the value of `resource` would be a mapping, rather than a string.

Notice the difference in syntax highlighting, compared to the yaml in the question with the `|` removed:

```yaml
sylius_admin_channel:
    resource: 
        alias: sylius.channel
        section: admin
        templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
        except: ['show']
        redirect: update
        grid: sylius_admin_channel
        permission: true
        vars:
            all:
                subheader: sylius.ui.configure_channels_available_in_your_store
                templates:
                    form: "@SyliusAdmin/Channel/_form.html.twig"
            index:
                icon: share alternate
    type: sylius.resource
```